# Create Synonym: listview - for the tag: 'list-view'

Tags: feature-request, tags

Suggest to create a synonym for the tag: list-view

new synonym: listview

Comment: The `list-view` tag exists. The `listview` tag does not. What is it you are looking for?

Comment: just to create a synonym to list-view

Comment: But there is no `listview` tag. Why would I create a tag just for synonym?

Comment: so the next time someone writes: listview, it will automatically be tagged as list-view